# Ooyala player: how to stop playback

Tags: objective-c, ios, ooyala

Is there a way to explicitly stop the playback for ooyala player? I can find `pause` but cannot find `stop`, also, in their website:

http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_destroyplayer.html

it says I can "destroy" a player, but I couldn't find the method either.

Comment: There's a code sample on the page you linked.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried the sample code, you first see a list of videos, you can tap any one and go to next screen which plays the video, when you go back, it just pause the video, remove the player's video from superview and then release the player.

Answer (score 0):

The destroy function should work if you are using the V3 player.  Do you have a test page that reproduces the issue?